# Why are maps made on Google Fusion Tables, using KML file format, not rendering properly?

Tags: kml, google-fusion-tables

On this particular map of mine, the feature in Fusion Tables seems to only approximate the geo-locators that I have specifically inputted.

In fact, it takes every ***second*** point and plots it out, making some very weird shapes.

At first I thought it was an issue with the coding. But after repeatedly checking back, it turned out the points had no problem, and they aligned perfectly.

The display was messing up, especially the "preview KML" option, although things usually get blurred in there and I don't use it that often, so this should be fine.

It doesn't even go over Google's own maximum "limit" of a million characters per element's object.

To clarify, however, this happens even if/when I refresh, go full-screen, publish, or share the document-type.

I've been using Fusion Tables for a long time, yet it's never given me this problem before. What's going on, how can its "problem" be fixed, and what should be done, in order to return this issue to its original state?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like some generalizing of data from either import into or fusion tables or when data is requested. Would advise not to use Google Fusion tables as they are shutting the service down later this year (3rd December 2019) https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/9185417

Comment: Mapperz, thanks for the inquiry and I am aware. However, it works fine when I split up that particular piece into multiple things. What would you advise as a good alternative, since I have not been able to find a good one that really suits my needs (simple map-making and data viz)

Comment: Anna see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37075/what-are-cloud-based-alternatives-to-google-fusion-tables